# Django, keep both global and local STATIC folders

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new in Django, coming from PHP and node mostly.
By default, I understand that every app needs to have its own static folder, which is ok for me but I also need to have a global static folder to serve resources that are common to all apps.
The problem is if I add to **settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"), 
]
```

I achieve the result of having a common global folder, but then the **app-level static folders** do not work anymore. Is there a way to keep both approaches? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am as well very new to django, and dont't fully understand what I am saying, but it appears that I did the same thing and it somehow worked, `STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]`
do you have this under INSTALLED_APPS = [] 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in settings.py, also are you using a database for your project

Comment: Yeah, ```django.contrib.staticfiles``` is there and then ```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')``` the problem is, when I use ```{% load static %}``` in templates now it refers to the static folder at root-level but **I do not have a way to create dynamic links to the static folders at app-level**